# how the json string is converted automatically into javascript object while using @json() directive?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

**laravel-10**

```
@php
    $student = ["name" => "John Doe", "age" => 20, "grade" => "A"];   
@endphp
<script>
    var data3 = @json($student);
    console.log(data3);
</script>
```

If the data passed from PHP to JavaScript using @json() is passed as a JSON string then
here in  this code why when we log the data3 to the console i.e. console.log(data3) then this  is the output
{name: 'John Doe', age: 20, grade: 'A'}
if the data passed from PHP to JavaScript using @json() is passed as a JSON string then shouldnot this  be  the  output
'{"name": 'John Doe', "age": 20, "grade": 'A'}'
because  this is the  JSON string.
It may sound like a stupid question

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `@json(...)` blade directive is compiled via the [`compileJson()` method of the `CompilesJson.php` trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesJson.php) (assuming the Blade directives are all defined from `compile{Directive}()`), so all it's doing is `<?php echo json_encode(...) ?>`, which is the typical way you'd convert a PHP variable to JS. There's nothing fancy happening here. Sidenote, you can also use `JS::from()`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#rendering-json.

Comment: _"If the data passed from PHP to JavaScript using @json() is passed as a JSON string"_ - what has stopped you from verifying if that assumption was actually true - by simply _checking_ what the generated HTML output of this template actually looks like?